# background image not showing on nested <nav>

Tags: html, css, background-image, clearfix

I have a `<header>` that has a nested `<div>` and `<nav>`. I have set a background image in css using `background-image: url();` and it displays fine on the `<header>` and `<div>` but not the `<nav>`. It seems to work when `<nav>` has a set height, but not otherwise. What's weird is that header doesn't have a set height either, but the image shows fine on there.

I'm thinking the problem is that `<nav>` contains floating elements and has a clearfix applied but `<header>` doesn't, but I have no idea how to go about working around this and google has been no help.

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/mattierae/pen/vLEeLO) of the problem (I use scss preprocessor fyi but codepen allows you to see compiled if you don't like that).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `:before` class with `:after`

```
nav {
    //clearfix
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Hope I will helps you.